# Sitecore.EDS.Core.Exceptions.InvalidMessageException error while using EXM

Tags: exm

**Environment:** Sitecore 9.2 & SXA 1.8

I have created an Automated Email Campaign while running the quick test I am facing this error:

```
2916 16:47:37 INFO  Registered email: {personal-email-here}
2916 16:47:37 INFO  Test Dispatch Message (Testing): Started
  Message Id:      {0DDCFB68-5348-41C4-BDA6-32056770DD40}
  Message Path:    /sitecore/content/Email/Messages/2020/05/27T115133/Testing
  Included Recipient Lists: 
  Excluded Recipient Lists: 

MessageTaskRunner worker thread 21 16:47:37 ERROR Message sending error:System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.EDS.Core.Exceptions.InvalidMessageException: Failed to send the email message due to incorrect data.
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatTransportClient.SendAsync(Email message)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<RetryOnFault>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<SendTaskAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider.<SendEmailAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchProviderBase.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.SendEmail.SendEmail.Process(SendMessageArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.PipelineHelper.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.TestMessageTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Sitecore.EDS.Core.Exceptions.InvalidMessageException: Failed to send the email message due to incorrect data.
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatTransportClient.SendAsync(Email message)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<RetryOnFault>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<SendTaskAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider.<SendEmailAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchProviderBase.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()<---

2916 16:47:37 INFO  Critical Error:
One or more errors occurred.


2916 16:47:37 INFO  
2916 16:47:37 INFO  Test Dispatch Message (Testing): Finished
  Result:          ABORTED
  Message Id:      {0DDCFB68-5348-41C4-BDA6-32056770DD40}
  Message Path:    /sitecore/content/Email/Messages/2020/05/27T115133/Testing
  Recipients Processed:    0
```

**CustomSMTP.config:**

```
<smtpSettings type="Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.SmtpSettings, Sitecore.EDS.Core" singleInstance="true">
          <server>smtp.sendgrid.net</server>
          <port>587</port>
          <userName>apikey</userName>
          <password>password</password>
          <authenticationMethod>LOGIN</authenticationMethod>
          <startTls>false</startTls>
          <proxySettings ref="exm/eds/proxySettings" />
        </smtpSettings>
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: How is your EXM configured for sending the mails? Custom smtp? If so, is that correctly configured?

Comment: yes, I am using SendGrid as CustomSMTP. It is configured correctly. Please check the edit. Thanks.

Comment: @PSS - did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @Calum yes, I guess it was related to SMTP settings, send requests were blocked. If you want to debug EXM on your local, try this tool - https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP.

Comment: Thanks @PPS - I already use Papercut :) I have posted my resolution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was receiving this error and looking at the SMTP response in the Sitecore logs, specifically `readSmtpResponse:` I could see that the cause of the error was that the `from address` I was using was `not allowed to send as` - I updated the from address to the correct address and I began to see emails being sent without error.